# In the runtime chain extension, should we be charging weight if we are reading a `StorageMap`?

Tags: ink, runtime, weight, pallet-contracts, chain-extension

If we have the storage map `DummyStorageMap` in `pallet-example`

And we read its value under the key `key` by calling `DummyStorageMap::<T>::get(key)` in the runtime chain extension (https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/trait.ChainExtension.html#) , **should we be charging weight** (https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/struct.Environment.html#method.charge_weight)?

I know we are obviously supposed to charge weight if we execute an extrinsic of a pallet in the runtime chain extension, but what about if we read a storage map / storage value?

Thanks

@bkchr :)

Comment: You should charge a read. Check this question and the code link:
https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6867/charge-weight-and-weight-info-in-chain-extension

Answer (score 1):

If you are not doing complex calculations in your runtime, most of the time the storage reading/writing should dominate your weight. With 2D weights which also include the increase of the proof size, reading storage will be more important to your weight calculation.

So, yes you need to charge weight for only reading.

Comment: so if we read a query a single key in a `StorageMap` - are we supposed to charge this weight manually by doing `env.charge_weight(T::DbWeight::get().reads(1))?`? Thanks

Comment: Furthermore, I noticed that it says here that we can benchmark our chain extension functions on Substrate: "In order to be able to charge the correct weight for the functions defined by a chain extension benchmarks must be written, too" (https://crates.parity.io/pallet_contracts/chain_extension/index.html#benchmarking and https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/1910/684)? Is this true? I thought we could only benchmark pallets calls in Substrate currently?

Comment: You can basically benchmark any kind of code.